# Excel datetime objects crash my Python 3.7 shell

Tags: excel, python-3.x, xlwings

I'm using the **xlwings** library for simple operations on some excel sheets.
For some reason my shell does not allow me to read in the values of Excel datetime objects.

For example, calling the value in L2 (2nd row, 12th column) will crash my Python 3.7 shell, and restart it:

```
#setup
import xlwings as wing
mybook = wing.Book("some_sheet.xlsx")
mysheet = book.sheets['Sheet 1']

# the line of code that crashes my shell (picture of excel sheet included)
mysheet.range(2,12).value         #row 2, column 12
```

I have tried converting values to text, but this gives weird 5-number strings (might be workable).
I have tried looking for a solution elsewhere.

*Can anyone point me in the right direction to work with these Excel datetime values in Python?*

[image: example]

Comment: I believe xlwings supports .value2. Try mysheet.range(2,12).value2

Comment: Does not work, Range object has no attribute value2. 'raw_value' gives the same error as 'value'.

Comment: Does it work with python 3.6? If yes, then it might be a 3.7 issue, I've opened an issue for now: https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/issues/914

Comment: This is an issue in pywin32, I opened an issue there: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/issues/1221

Comment: @FelixZumstein Downgrading to 3.6 fixed my problem. Thanks for looking into the issue for future development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrading to Python 3.6 fixed this for me.

Comment: You can now use xlwings with Python 3.7 by installing the pywin32 version from here: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32

Comment: With pywin32 224 this is now fixed on the official pypi release.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by installing 'pip install pywin32==300'